# how to save dimension of a div into mvc4 database table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my model to save the div width and height which i want to save this in decimal value when i am resizing div in view

Eg :50.178

but it is saving 50

```
 public decimal FormElementWidth { get; set; }
 public decimal FormElementHeight { get; set; }
```

This is my Controller class

```
 public void UpdateFormElementDimension(long formElementId, int elementWidthPercent, int elementHeightPercent)
        {
            //long userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);

            FormElement formElement = db.FormElements.Find(formElementId);
            formElement.FormElementWidth = elementWidthPercent;
            formElement.FormElementHeight = elementHeightPercent;
            db.Entry(formElement).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

so how i can save this decimal value when resizing div in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use float Attribute in your model and when posting the value parse your value in float as below

```
float myDecimalValue = float.Parse(yourValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it is saving 50

That's because `UpdateFormElementDimension()`'s parameters `elementWidthPercent` and `elementHeightPercent` parameters are of type `int`.

You most likely want them to be `decimal`.

You could've found this out by putting a breakpoint inside the method and inspect the variables' content.

Comment: i have change it to decimal ..then also getting same ans

Comment: @Neeraj what is "same ans"? Did you put a breakpoint in the action method, do you receive the values as decimal? How do they get sent to the controller, are you sure that call provides decimal values?

Comment: i have checked it using debug.writeline i am getting decimal number but it is not saving in table

Comment: What type is the column in the database?